# Download speed for Open Hardware Monitor

Tags: c#, download-speed, openhardwaremonitor

I'm making some changes for Open Hardware Monitor. I will add the network adapter download and upload speed. But when I calculate the download speed I get a wrong calculation.

I can't use a timer to calculate the correct download speed because of the auto update in OHM.
In the source here you can see how I calculate the download speed (in Mb/s).

In the construct of the class i do:

```
IPv4InterfaceStatistics interfaceStats = netInterfaces.GetIPv4Statistics();

bytesSent = interfaceStats.BytesSent;
bytesReceived = interfaceStats.BytesReceived;

stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
```

When the update method is called (in some random times) I do this:

```
IPv4InterfaceStatistics interfaceStats = netInterfaces.GetIPv4Statistics();

stopWatch.Stop();
long time = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

if (time != 0)
{
    long bytes = interfaceStats.BytesSent;
    long bytesCalc = ((bytes - bytesSent)*8);

    usedDownloadSpeed.Value = ((bytesCalc / time) * 1000)/1024;
    bytesSent = bytes;                 
}
```

Hope someone can see my issue?

[image]

Added screenshot

Comment: How do you mean wrong? When you divide two integral types `(bytesCalc/time)` you get a truncated integral result which may be the issue.

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but a KB is 1024 bytes, and a MB is 1024 KBs. I see a 1000 and a 1000000 in your calculations.

Comment: I have changed my calculation in double bytesCalc = (((double)bytes - (double)bytesSent)*8);
usedDownloadSpeed.Value = (float)((double)(bytesCalc / time) * 1000);
But it doesn't work. I has the same value than with the old calculation.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There where a few conversion issues with my previous code.
Now I have this source and it works.
Tnx all for answering.

```
    interfaceStats = netInterfaces.GetIPv4Statistics();

        //Calculate download speed
        downloadSpeed.Value = Convert.ToInt32(interfaceStats.BytesReceived - bytesPreviousReceived) / 1024F;

        bytesPreviousReceived = interfaceStats.BytesReceived;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following changes should help...

```
speed = netInterfaces.Speed / 1048576L;
```

If I recall correctly, the `Speed` property is a `long` and when you divide it by an `int`, you end up with a truncated result. Which brings us to a similar set of changes in your other calculation...

```
usedDownloadSpeed.Value = ((bytesCalc / time) * 1000L)/1024L;
```

... assuming that `usedDownloadSpeed.Value` is also a `long` to make sure you're not getting any truncated values with implicit conversion of your results or calculations. If you want to be doubly sure you have the casting correctly, use `Convert.ToInt64()`.

Comment: The usedDownloadSpeed.Value is an float. So I must convert the long to a float value.